# How to do an while loop in batch through command line args

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run a batch script through the command line arguments to avoid writing a batch script to file every time I need it.

The sample batch script is

```
:loop
timeout /t 1
goto loop
```

I pass it to cmd.exe with the command line

```
cmd.exe /C ":loop & timeout /t 1 & goto loop"
```

It works for commands like timeout, but it doesn't work if I include labels such as loop.

It simply exits without saying anything.

Is it possible to do labels and if else statements through the /C command in batch?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not a while loop but an infinite one, that's why I edited the question title. Anyway, please clarify what you mean by "through command line arguments"…

Comment: There's no "while" loop in your question. If you don't know how to ask questions, read [ask].

Comment: Perhaps stop assuming that everyone doesn't know what you're talking about but that your wording is unclear. The snippet you show, as well as the answer you received create an infinite loop. Labels alone or the lack thereof don't magically turn a loop into a "while" loop, which is a very specific type of loop.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, but the answer claims it doesn't require labels which are ignored in the /C command. Which may be a possible solution. Also you should know that while true is still a while loop.

Comment: There is no "while" keyword in Windows batch scripting. If you need help with a particular problem, it's up to you to properly describe said problem.

Comment: I voted to close your question due to lack of clarity, because it is up to you to make your post as clear as possible, so that others can provide a helpful answer even without sitting in front of your computer…

Comment: It's a shame that you find people asking for clarification time wasters. You found the "while" part of your question so important that you rolled back an edit and started discussing it, but nowhere have you explained that you actually want a conditional loop.

Comment: `Is it possible to do labels and if else statements through the /C command?` - No. Labels and `GOTO`'s are only valid within batchfiles. What you pass to `cmd /c` isn't a batchfile, but a command line. What hinders you to pass a batchfile (like `cmd /c "myscript.bat"`?

Comment: @Stephan that is redundant. Also I already explained why on the first line of my post.

Comment: yes, I have a feeling you need to read it several times to realize it: a command line is not a batchfile and follows different rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use labels on the command line, but if you're looking for an infinite loop, it's possible to abuse the `for /L` command so that the counter never reaches its target.

```
for /L %A in (,,) do timeout /t 1
```

Note that if you want to run this in a script, you need to change `%A` to `%%A` because of how escaping `%`s works.